# Destroy the [slowly-changing-dimension]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[slowly-changing-dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slowly-changing-dimension)

The tag has to go. It's not useful, has no tag wiki, sounds unprofessional, and only has two questions under it. It does seem like it's a feature provided by SQL Server, but then it's a meta tag that shouldn't exist.

Comment: This potentially seems like it might be a useful tag. Probably it should have been merged with scd http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scd

Comment: @MartinSmith I'll add the scd tag back on them then. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Don't merge it. The tag name is too ambiguous.

Comment: @bjb568 A merge may not be necessary here, but the original questions related to `[slowly-changing-dimension]` needed the clean up and retag to `[scd]`, which I've done.

Comment: Yes. Good. Ok. Chars.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You bothered to write a meta post for 2 questions?

Well… I removed the tag.